# "User does not have permission to comment on this post" error

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, comments

I am attempting to post a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13508175/251589), but I am getting the following error:

[image: User does not have permission to comment on this post]

I have 4000+ reputation on Stackoverflow so I don't think that should be a problem.

I looked [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) page but couldn't find anything that applied.

This is the comment I am attempting to post:

> This code does work but I am fairly certain that it has a memory leak.  [To avoid this use removeRow](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.15/doc/usage/Working-with-Widgets.md#destroying-rendered-widgets)

To make sure that nothing funny is going on, I also tried to post this:

> Test comment - Will this comment work?

Comment: Are you 100% for sure logged in on SO?

Comment: I see you were able to post the comment. Maybe some temp glitch in the system?

Comment: Resolved.  Not sure what was going on.  I suspect that it was a login issue.  I checked and made sure that I was logged in but who knows.  For anyone else having this issue: Restart your browser and try again.

Comment: @Oded can the message be changed to something like "You must be logged in to post comments" in case users somehow able to submit a comment while not logged in? (see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267825/152859))

Comment: I had this issue a few days ago, and opened a RFE, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390265/176236

Answer (score 7):

I <strike>am</strike> was having the same issue. This is the answer that I'm replying to:
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/6136/209

This is the comment that I'm trying to post:

> Actually, you can get nearer to the *geometric center* of the mass, which accounts for the higher local gravity field (and tidal forces). Note that at the same distance from the (center) of the black hole and the (center) of the star, the black hole's gravity will be **lower**.

No need for a screenshot, the OP's screenshot shoes exactly the issue. I'm most certainly logged in, and .... **wait**!

**Refreshing the page shows that I was logged in. Going to other questions showed that I was logged in. Going to the astronomy.SE page showed that I *wasn't* logged in, but the bar at the top of the page welcomed me and informed me that I could reload the page to log in. Reloading that page allowed me to go *back to the tab with the comment* and submit it even without refreshing that page.**

Comment: That sounds familiar.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue being unable to post a comment despite it showing I was logged in. I think the problem was I had cleared my cookies but left a stackoverflow page open which thought I was still logged in.

Closing the tab and going back to the site it prompted me to log in again and I was able to post my comment.