# Show "User is not logged in" instead of "User has no permission"

Tags: feature-request

See the issue ["User does not have permission to comment on this post" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237992/176236)

The error message should be clearer, stating that the comment can not be submitted because the user is not logged in (actually: the session expired). Which is the actual reason in that case (in the linked question).

Comment: SE sessions normally do not expire. You can stay logged in for years.

Comment: Heh, that's what I suggested there in a comment. (Oded used to be a developer in SE back then.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I've had sessions expire at times.

Comment: At times, yes, sure. I’m not saying it never happens. But it does not happen regularly, only when there is some sort of trouble.

Answer (score -4):

So, there are a few problems with this:

1. How does it know that **you have an account where you’re not logged in?** Or do you imagine showing it to every unregistered user who tries to comment? If so, then you are saying something impossible to them: To comment you need to login to **an already existing account**. Not sign up, but only log in.
2. The bug is pretty annoying and should probably eventually be fixed, but changing this feature is probably more complex and unnecessary.
3. This is pretty low on the list of problems and it is literally **not reproducible**. This would only help you and handful of people. There are better uses of SE’s time ([and worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows?cb=1)).

Comment: 1. It doesn't. It knows nobody is logged in. So it says "Not logged in, can not comment" To everybody who tries to comment but not logged in. This is how most websites behave.

Comment: Thats my point, it cant be done bc it cant know @DavidBalažic

Comment: What do you mean? What can not be done? It seems like we talk about two entirely different things.

Comment: You cant make this feature bc how will it know that you own an account if you arent logged into it? @DavidBalažic

Comment: Why would it need that? It knows nobody is logged in. And that is what it should write. Like I wrote above. That comments can not be submitted without being logged on.

Comment: 3. It can be reproduced by deleting the cookies. Good enough for testing.

Comment: Well one shouldn't delete the cookies. We dont fix stuff for preventing people from actively trying to cause a problem with it. If someone decides to delete their account and therefore cant comment then we have no prob with that @DavidBalažic

Comment: The problem is that most not logged in users have no account and no wish to make one. This also gives something impossible, as it asks to log in, not sign up @DavidBalažic

Comment: 1. People without an account will never see this message, as they are not shown the "submit comment" GUI.
2. This problem does not occur because people delete their cookies. That was only a suggestion how to test a fix.